# Data not being shown when template is included in another template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a html file that contains the following line:

```
core.html
{% include 'events/events.html' %}
```

And I have this other template:

```
events.html
{% for event in events %}
    {{ event.event_name }} <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

When I open the URL that loads the `events.html` it perfectly shows the data:

```
Evento 1 
Pentaho Workshop
```

But when I open the main URL that loads `core.html` it shows me nothing. If I write "blabla" out of the `for` block it is shown!!!

**Events -> views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from models import Events

def events_index(request):
    events = Events.objects.all()
    return render(request, "events/events.html", locals())
```

**Core -> views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def core_index(request):
    return render(request, "core/core.html", locals())
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: What do the views that correspond to `core.html` and `events.html` look like?

Comment: @ob1quixote just updated the question to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you navigate to the URL for `events.html` that invokes the `events_index` view which loads the `events` object into the template context via `events = Events.objects.all()`. The `core_index` view doesn't include `events` in the context, so there's nothing for the loop to process. If you add an import for the Events model and `events = Events.objects.all()` to `core_index` things will work more like you expect.

Comment: It worked! Are there anyway to put all the logic and process within the app to reuse it? The way I was expecting it to work is the idea I want to express... is there any way of doing it?

Comment: I think I understand what you want, and you _can_ include a view in another view, for some value of include, _q.v._ ["Can I call a view from within another view?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808329/can-i-call-a-view-from-within-another-view). However, I don't think I would. If you need to reference the Events model in both views, so be it. Views should be compositions of models and the necessary logic to return the rendered HTML you need. I think it's okay to reference the same model in more than one view.