# Django redirect by calling function view?

Tags: django, django-views

I need to redirect while keeping the original request. Is this approach inline with Django 3 logic or am I creating some furute catastrofe?

```
def final_view(request):
    # use some_new_variable to do stuff and then display it in the template
    return render(request, another_template_name, {})

def original_view(request):
    # do stuff
    request.some_new_variable = "x"
    return final_view(request)
```

Comment: A redirect is a HTTP response that says to the browser: "hey make a request to another address", so the original request is *gone*.

Comment: It looks similar to this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808329/can-i-call-a-view-from-within-another-view

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but you could always pass "some_new_variable" via the URL

For instance:

**views.py**

```
def original_view(request):
    x = # do your stuff here
    return redirect('final_view_url', var=x)

def final_view(request, var)
    final_var = # do some additional stuff with var here
    return render(request, another_template_name)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('/final_view/<var>', views.final_view, name="final_view_url")
```

So you send your original request to "original_view", do some stuff, then pass that variable into the URL to "final_view"